# Adding column using make migration command error

Tags: laravel, database-migration, laravel-migrations

I'm trying to add an `icon_path` column to an existing table called `tbl_device` 
by using `php artisan make:migration add_icon_path_to_tbl_device_table --table=tbl_device`

and after running `php artisan migrate`, it gives me this error.

```
PHP Fatal error:  Cannot declare class CreateFailedJobsTable, because the name is already in use in ...path\database\migrations\<date>_create_failed_jobs_table.php    
Cannot declare class CreateFailedJobsTable, because the name is already in use
```

I've also tried manually adding the `icon_path` column to the `create_tbl_device_table.php` migration and after running `php artisan migrate` it says `Nothing to migrate`.

I think I followed all the instructions.. any idea where I went wrong?

Comment: Did you  ran `php artisan queue:table` twice? You have  two migrations called `create_failed jobs_table`or `create_jobs_table` or `create_session_table` in your migration folder? If so, then  delete the duplicate from your migration directory and try again. r. Run `composer dump-autoload` afterwards to be on a save side.

Comment: The error shows that you have 2 migrations files trying to create a failed_jobs table. Please check your migrations folder and make sure there are no duplicated files. This error not related to adding a column migration file.

Answer (score 0):

Call artisan migrate command only for your specific migration using:

`php artisan migrate --path=/database/migrations/my_migrations`

And see if it works.